# Seemingly useful and unusable parent property

Tags: c#, .net, listviewitem

I have a class that desccends from ListviewItem.

When I create an instance of this class, I assign to the instance some properties inherited from its ancestor, ListViewItem.

However, the EnsureVisible property is problematic.

If I do this:

```
base.EnsureVisible = true;
```

...I get, "Cannot assign to 'EnsureVisible' because it is a 'method group'"

..and if I do this:

```
base.EnsureVisible(true);
```

...I get, "No overload for method 'EnsureVisible' takes 1 arguments"

The name of the property makes it sound useful, but how can I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is that `EnsureVisible` is a no-argument method and not a property.  It has the following signature

```
public virtual void EnsureVisible();
```

You can't assign a value to it.  Calling the method itself forces the item to become visible (or at least requests it)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

```
base.EnsureVisible();
```

Answer (score 1):

As first step take a look at MSDN for [ListViewItem.EnsureVisible()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.ensurevisible.aspx) method.

Maybe you won't need to use it very often but somday you'll be happy it's there! Imagine you have a `ListView` with a lot of items and, for any reason (MSDN talks about validation) you need to make one of them visible (to read "visible" as visible to user, in the set of items actually displayed), then you can call that method (without any parameter) to ensure the `ListView` will be scrolled to ensure that the item you want to highlight will be inside the area where user can see it without any other scrolling.